# using string::find to search for words that are distinct. Having problems with smaller words like "is."

Tags: c++

For an assignment, I am supposed to enter a paragraph of text and from that paragraph of text generate a list of distinct words and how often they appear. for example, a phrase "`pie eating pie smile`" has `3 distinct` words.

The main problem I'm running into is that string::find sees words such as "`is`" in the word "`comprise`," so the word "`is`" is **not distinct**.

Comment: I would reconsider the overall approach. You might be better off just reading word by word and tracking in a map the number of occurrences

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a string extractor to read words from the file, insert them into a `std::set`, then print out the distinct words in the result:

```
std::istream in("yourfile.txt");

std::set<std::string> words {std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in), 
                             std::istream_iterator<std::string>()};

std::copy(words.begin(), words.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

To get frequency of appearance, switch to a `std::map<std::string, size_t>`, and increment the entry for each word as you read it:

```
std::map<std::string, size_t> counts;
std::string word;

while (infile >> word)
  ++counts[word];
```

As-is, this will keep the words in alphabetical order. If you don't care about that, you might (or might not) get a speed boost from using `std::unordered_map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm should go like this:

1. Read a line.
2. Separate the tokens (words).
3. Increase each found token's count
4. repeat at 1 unless EOF.

You should be able to extract and process each token for itself.

Do not try to find the tokens in the untokenized input.
Tip: Look at `std::unordered_map<string, size_t>`. It allows you to efficiently find tokens and update their counts.